# Skip to the next lesson, or the first of the next module

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble creating a script to advance to the next lesson of a course.

My structure is this

```js
const course = {
  title: 'Course name',
  duration: '1h 30min',
  modules: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'first module',
      lessons: [
        {
          id: 1,
          moduleId: 1,
          title: 'lesson 1',
          video: 'https://video.com/any.mp4',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          moduleId: 1,
          title: 'lesson 2',
          video: 'https://video.com/any.mp4',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'second module',
      lessons: [
        {
          id: 1,
          moduleId: 2,
          title: 'lesson 1',
          video: 'https://video.com/any.mp4',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          moduleId: 2,
          title: 'lesson 2',
          video: 'https://video.com/any.mp4',
        },
      ],
    }
  ],
}
```

When the video for the lesson reaches the end, a hook is active and a script must be executed, but I am having difficulty creating this script, the business rule is: *Go to the next lesson, if there is none, go to the first lesson next module, if there is no next module, do nothing*.

I have the reactive data that the user is currently on

```js
const currentModule = {
  id: 1,
  title: 'first module',
}

const currentLesson = {
  id: 2,
  moduleId: 1,
  title: 'lesson 2',
  video: 'https://video.com/any.mp4',
}
```

I would need to fill this out:

```js
let nextLesson = {}
let nextModule = {}
```

What can I try to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let nextModule = {};
let nextLesson = {};

// Keep track of the module you are in
const currentModuleIndex = course.modules.map((module) => module.id).indexOf(currentModule.id);

// Keep track of the lesson you are in
const _currentModule = course.modules.filter((module) => module.id === currentModule.id)[0];
const currentLessonIndex = _currentModule.lessons.map((lesson) => lesson.id).indexOf(currentLesson.id)

// If you are at the end lesson of a module and there is no other modules left
if (course.modules.length === currentModuleIndex + 1) {
  console.log('you are at the end lesson');
} else
// If the current lesson is the end of the lessons in the current module
if (course.modules[currentModuleIndex].lessons.length === currentLessonIndex + 1) {
  // next module will be +1 the module you were tracking
  nextModule = {
    id: course.modules[currentModuleIndex + 1].id,
    title: course.modules[currentModuleIndex + 1].title
  }

  // next lesson is just the data from the first lesson of that module
  nextLesson = {
    id: course.modules[currentModuleIndex + 1].lessons[0].id,
    moduleId: course.modules[currentModuleIndex + 1].id,
    title: course.modules[currentModuleIndex + 1].lessons[0].title,
    video: course.modules[currentModuleIndex + 1].lessons[0].video,
  }
} else {
  // next module is the same as the current
  nextModule = currentModule;

  // next lesson will be +1 to the lesson you were tracking
  nextLesson = {
    id: course.modules[currentModuleIndex].lessons[currentLessonIndex + 1].id,
    moduleId: course.modules[currentModuleIndex].id,
    title: course.modules[currentModuleIndex].lessons[currentLessonIndex + 1].title,
    video: course.modules[currentModuleIndex].lessons[currentLessonIndex + 1].video,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It's simply figuring out the index of the current module and lesson, and then checking if there is a next in line. (You could probably refactor this to be neater.)

```js
const course = {
  title: 'Course name',
  duration: '1h 30min',
  modules: [{id: 1, title: 'first module', lessons: [{id: 1,moduleId: 1,title: 'lesson 1', video: 'https://video.com/any.mp4'},{id: 2,moduleId: 1,title: 'lesson 2',video: 'https://video.com/any.mp4'}]},{id: 2,title: 'second module',lessons: [{id: 1,moduleId: 2,title: 'lesson 1',video: 'https://video.com/any.mp4'},{id: 2,moduleId: 2,title: 'lesson 2',video: 'https://video.com/any.mp4'}]}]}
const currentLesson = {
  id: 2,
  moduleId: 1,
  title: 'lesson 2',
  video: 'https://video.com/any.mp4',
}

const getNextModule = ( {id: currentLessonId, moduleId: currentModuleId} ) => {
  let nextModule;
  let nextLesson;
  course.modules.forEach((module, currentModuleIndex) => {
    if (module.id === currentModuleId) {
      // find index of the current lesson for the current module
      const currentLessonIndex = module.lessons.findIndex( lesson => lesson.id === currentLessonId );
      if (!module.lessons[currentLessonIndex + 1]) {
        // there is no next lesson for the current module, take the next module
        // and its first lesson
        nextModule = {...course.modules[currentModuleIndex + 1]};
        nextLesson = {...nextModule.lessons[0]};
        return;
      }
      // take the current module and the next lesson
      nextModule = {...module};
      nextLesson = {...nextModule.lessons[currentLessonIndex + 1]};
    }
  })

  return {nextModule, nextLesson};
}
console.log( getNextModule(currentLesson) );
```